# Проблема с кодировкой

Tags: кодировка, c++

Добрый день, проблема с кодировками.

```
    string name = "увыц";
    cout << name;
```

Выводит краказяблы, пробовал так:

```
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    string name = "увыц";
    cout << name;
```

И ещё пару способов с форумов, не помогло.

Comment: какие именно кряказяблы? может у Вас редактор в utf-8 сохраняет текст.

Comment: вообще знаки вопросов, если брать этот вариант

Comment: Бросьте винду - и будет Вам счастье.

Comment: Да я бы бросил, но по заданию нужно написать проект под неё- родимую)

Answer (score 1):

если у вас windows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");   
    SetConsoleCP(866);

    string s = "абвгде";

    cout << s  << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
абвгде
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

Comment: выводит знаки вопросов, компилировал в vs2010

Comment: у вас видимо проблемы с системными шрифтами, возможно шрифт вовсе отсутствует или шрифт чисто английский

Comment: если так, то выводит ровно то, что я ввожу, и русский тоже. SetConsoleCP(1251); SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); string name; cin >> name; cout << name;

Comment: у вас редактор сохранил текст в utf-8.

Comment: студия как-то сохраняет, но я могу изменить кодировку, на какую?

Comment: Мой совет — никогда не используйте `string`, только `wstring`. Иначе к проблемам с кодировкой консоли у вас добавятся проблемы с кодировкой вашего редактора, вашей системы, системная кодовая страница и тому подобная дребедень.

Comment: wstring name = L"ываыв";
    wcout << name;
в воем первом варианте выводит Ничего), в во втором рекомендованном- страшные иероглифы.

Comment: @fortunado: на SO советуют так:

    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <io.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>

    using namespace std;

    int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
    {
        _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT); // колдовство здесь
        wstring s = L"begin ываыв end";
        wcout << s << endl;
        return 0;
    }

Answer (score 1):

так заработало, действительно были проблемы с кодировкой в системе, если явно указать, то все работает с wstring, со string-ом не хотит.

Рабочий вариант:

```
        std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
        system("chcp 65001");
        wstring name = L"увыц";
        wcout << name;
```

спс за внимание.

Comment: @fortunado, уверены что убогим виндовым юникодом хотите связываться?

Или все-таки в программе cp1251 (обычная кодировка файлов и т.п. в винде), а на консоли стандартная cp866?

Вы поищите прямо  по ХэшКоду похожие вопросы. Там есть простые работающие примеры.

Поиск через гугл:  

    site:hashcode.ru слова Вашего запроса

[пример ответа](http://hashcode.ru/questions/198586)